# Show Fields in WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, field, wpfdatagrid

How can I display fields of a struct inside of a WPF `DataGrid`?

```
public struct Hotspot
{
    public uint NamePtr;
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public int Z;

    public string Name { get; set; }
}
...
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = Hotspots; // List<Hotspot>
```

The `DataGrid` only shows the Name-property, if I set the `ItemSource`.
But I need the 3 fields (X, Y, Z) also to be displayed.

I can't use a `class` because I have to marshal the "Hotspots" via. `Marshal.PtrToStructure`.

I could create a property for each field, but is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

My recomandation is that you use viewmodel when you need to bind, since you may get lack of memory when binding to a model that not impmelent INotifyPropertyChanged.

anyway.

What you are tying to do is to autogenerate columns?
why cant you create columns manually using XAML?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create properties and bind to those, as XAML cannot bind to fields.

This is a field:

```
public int Z;
```

and this is a property:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```